# AchievementsUI and LeaderboardsUI won't popup. Signing in works and unlocked achievements popups work

Tags: c#, google-play, google-play-services, unity-game-engine

So. I have made a game with unity 5. And i have downloaded and configured the google play services plugin. I can sign in and unlock achievements with success. But for some reason the 
    `Social.ShowAchievementsUI();`
and 
    `Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();`
Won't work. Or anything won't popup.

So I'm trying to show the list of achievements and show the list of leaderboards available. I have 5 Achievements and 4 Leaderboards. I have this version of the game on Google Play alpha test. With the 2 buttons for Opening achievements menu and leaderboards but those won't work.
My code for login is:

```
void Start () {
    if (PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IsAuthenticated() == false)
    { 
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
        SignIn();
    }

void SignIn()
{
        Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
        {});
}
```

for showing `achievementsUI` :

```
public void ShowAchievementsUI()
{
    Social.ShowAchievementsUI();
}
```

for showing `Leaderboard ui`:

```
public void ShowLeaderboardsUI()
{
    Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
}
```

These 2 are called from buttons.

i am using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding:

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

To AndroidManifest.xml fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

First create a script for your PlayGames Commands. The script itself will just be a public class; however, all of the commands will be static so that you can call them from other scripts.

```
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayGamesScript : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    SignIn ();
}

// PRE: None
// POST: Logs player into Google Play Games
void SignIn()
{
    Social.localUser.Authenticate (success => {});
}

#region Achievements
// PRE: Achievement created in Google Play Developer and the 
// achievement has been achieved by the player
// POST: Unlocks the achievement for the player
public static void UnlockAchievement(string id)
{
    Social.ReportProgress(id, 100, success => { });
}

// PRE: Achievement created in Google Play Developer and set to Incremental
// achievement
// POST: Increments the achievement by selected steps established by 
// the stepsToIncrement variable
public static void IncrementAchievement(string id, int stepsToIncrement)
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IncrementAchievement(id, stepsToIncrement, success => { });
}

// PRE: Achievements created in Google Play Developer and player 
// is logged in
// POST: Shows the Achievements UI
public static void ShowAchievementsUI()
{
    if(PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IsAuthenticated())
        Social.ShowAchievementsUI();
    else
        Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success)=>{
            Social.ShowAchievementsUI();
        });
}
#endregion /Achievements

#region Leaderboards
// PRE: Leaderboard created in Google Play Developer and player is logged in
// POST: Reports the score to the leaderboard id specified for Google Play
public static void AddScoreToLeaderboard(string leaderboardId, long score)
{
    Social.ReportScore(score, leaderboardId, success => { });
}
// PRE: Leaderboard created in Google Play Developer and player is logged in
// POST: Accesses the PlayGamesScript to display the Leaderboard UI
public static void ShowLeaderboardsUI()
{
    if(PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IsAuthenticated())
        Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
    else
        Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success)=>{
            Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
        });
}
#endregion /Leaderboards

}
```

You call these functions from another script (the script that calls to view the leaderboard or achievement UI), for example:

```
public class GooglePlayUIController : MonoBehaviour {

    // PRE: Leaderboard created in Google Play Developer
    // POST: Accesses the PlayGamesScript to display the Leaderboard UI
    public void ShowLeaderboards() {
        PlayGamesScript.ShowLeaderboardsUI ();
    }

    // PRE: Achievements created in Google Play Developer
    // POST: Accesses the PlayGamesScript to display the Achievement UI
    public void ShowAchievements() {
        PlayGamesScript.ShowAchievementsUI();
    }
}
```

From there you can add these functions onto your buttons through the Unity editor on the OnClick() function; this is how I set mine up.

Of course, do not forget to add your resource data into Unity at the tabs Window --> Google Play Games --> Android Setup so that you may call the ID of each of your achievements, or call to the leaderboard id, via GPGSIds. For example,

```
// PRE: A game has been played until all lives equal zero
// POST: A score has been posted to the online leaderboards
private void PostScore() {
    PlayGamesScript.AddScoreToLeaderboard (GPGSIds.high_score, player.score);
}
```

Comment: so if i call them with in this case ShowAchievementsUI() on a button it won't work?
    
public void ShowAchievementsUI()
{
    Social.ShowAchievementsUI();
}

I have configured it right. I have achievement unlocked popups working and all that stuff. but the Social.ShowAchievementsUI() and Social.ShowLeaderboardUIi() won't work

Comment: This code you provided shouldn't change anything since it's similar to mine. I quess you didn't read the question.

Comment: actually its different as you are trying to open the UI directly as mine is accessing the function from a static function. I had the same issue you are facing and this was my solution. Check out this youtube video if you are still not finding the answer to your question....

Comment: Are you noticing the difference between the calls to PlayGamesPlatform and PlayGamesScript?

Comment: Going to try to access the function from static function. Keeping you updated

Comment: Didn't work. I was actually discussing about this thing with the creator of that video earlier. This is very confusing. Only thing that could cause it at this point is either Google Play's APP Signing, Or some kind of limitations of showing UI's in Alpha versions

Comment: still weird that you had that issue over such a small thing because my app is on alpha as we speak and it all works just fine without having to make that change.

Comment: Most people that have had this issue are using windows 8.0. Like me. The issue has something to do with the version of android studio or something with the windows 8 or any other modifier. It's weird. But the issue is fixed by typing that line to androidmanifest